# Add path to window.location without going to new page

Tags: javascript, html

Look at the example of the online store.
https://online-store-rs.netlify.app/
When you click to button "smartphones", "Apple", or place ranges, window location paths changes to
https://online-store-rs.netlify.app/?category=smartphones&brand=apple&price=90%E2%86%95899
How is it done? When in javascript I change window.location.path to something, page redirecting. How can I change only path without that redirecting?

Comment: you might be referring to `location.history` - specifically [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)? That allows you to change the displayed URL ( address bar ) without reloading the page.

Answer (score 2):

Please use `replaceState` (for modern browsers) or `pushState`.

```
window.history.replaceState(data, title, url);
window.history.pushState(data, title, url);
```